# New to python and looking for a hint to solve a syntax error

Tags: python

I'm trying to figure out whats wrong about the following code sample. Running this I end up with a syntax error on line 18. Can't figure out why though.

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy.integrate import odeint 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def hex(x, A):
    Tf = x[0]
    Tk = x[1]
    Nk = 0.1
    Tg = 300
    b = 0.2
    ag = 30
    k = 20
    Hvap = 80000
    cpg = 100
    cpk = 600
    ng = 30
    cpf = 600
    q = k * (Tf-Tk)
    n1 = ng * b * np.log(y2f/y2b)
    dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf)
    dTkdA = -q / (Nk * cpk)
    return [dTfdA, dTkdA]
```

Comment: Could you pls post the error.

Comment: What is the exact error and which line is line 18? I can't count that high.

Comment: what is Nf here `dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf)`? do you mean Nk?

Comment: `File "<ipython-input-64-a5fdfea79136>", line 18
    dTkdA = -q / (Nk * cpk)
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis on the line `dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing a bracket

```
dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf)
```

to

```
dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should write the equation as:

```
dTkdA = 0 - q / (Nk * cpk)
```

Comment: That's because of missing parenthesis on line 17:  `dTfdA = (ag * phi * (Hvap/cpg + (Tg-Tf)/(1-np.exp(-phi))) - q / (Nf * cpf))`